# Primefaces: open a dialog when an element in a pie chart is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to figure out how to open a dialog box when an element in a pie chart is clicked.  I'm new to Primefaces, so most of what I've found in searches are more complex examples than what I'm trying to accomplish.  The dialog box is opened using the Dialog Framework.  I've been able to open the dialog via a command button no problem, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't with the dialog itself.

Here's the initial page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <body>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
                >

    <p:panel header="Dashboard" toggleable="true">

    <h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{dashboardPieChart.pieModel1}" style="width:350px; height:200px" >

            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{dashboardPieChart.itemSelect}"/>

        </p:chart>

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:outputText id="out" value="#{dashboardPieChart.seriesText}" />

    </h:form>

</p:panel>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         PrimeFaces.info ('Info message');
         PrimeFaces.debug('Debug message');
         PrimeFaces.warn ('Warning message');
         PrimeFaces.error('Error message');
      </script>


</ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

And the backing bean:

```
package com.company.project.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.ItemSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardPieChart implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9056199453379512637L;

    private PieChartModel pieModel1;
    private String seriesText;

    /*
    public DashboardPieChart()
    {
        init();
    }
    */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("DashboardPieChart - inside init()");
        createPieModels();
    }

    public PieChartModel getPieModel1() {
        return pieModel1;
    }

    private void createPieModels() {
        createPieModel1();
    }

    private void createPieModel1() {
        pieModel1 = new PieChartModel();

        pieModel1.set("Proposals in Progress", 12);
        pieModel1.set("Proposals Completed", 15);

        pieModel1.setTitle("Proposals");
        pieModel1.setLegendPosition("w");
        pieModel1.setDiameter(100);
    }

    public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {

        String msgText = "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex();

        System.out.println (msgText);

        this.seriesText = msgText;

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("pieChartDrillDownDialog");
    }

    public String getSeriesText() {
        return seriesText;
    }

    public void setSeriesText(String seriesText) {
        this.seriesText = seriesText;
    }

}
```

and this is the dialog I'm trying to open:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
      > 

<h:head>
<title>Proposal Status Detail</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
        <h:form>

            <p:chart type="pie" model="#{dashboardPieChartDrillDown.pieModel}" style="width:350px; height:200px" >
            </p:chart>

        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work using remoteCommand:

XHTML:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="fnc" actionListener="#{playgroundController.showDialog()}"/>

<p:chart type="pie" model="#{playgroundController.pieModel1}" style="width:400px;height:300px">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{playgroundController.itemSelect}" oncomplete="fnc()" />
</p:chart>
```

BEAN:

```
public void showDialog() {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("pieChartDrillDownDialog");
}

public void itemSelect(ItemSelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Item selected",
                    "Item Index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Series Index:" + event.getSeriesIndex());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Comment: I don't see your remote command fnc() defined in your example code.

Comment: OK, the remote command clue definitely helped.  I was able to get my code to work.  I'll add an answer later that shows all of the code.